# mysql_fetch_array() recieving null value

Tags: php

Cant figure out why my query isn't returning the 'make'. I've checked the SQL many times.

```
$DBConnect = @mysqli_connect("host.com", "name","pass", "database")
    Or die ("<p>Unable to connect to the database server.</p>". "<p>Error code ". mysqli_connect_errno().": ". mysqli_connect_error()). "</p>"; 

$query = "SELECT make FROM inventory";
$makeresult= @mysql_query($DBConnect, $query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($makeresult)) {
    $options .="<option>" . $row['make'] . "</option>";
}
```

Comment: remove the `@` and see if there's an error

Comment: You sometimes  use mysqli_ and sometimes mysql_ .

Comment: Ive changed the code to use mysqli_ and it works. Didn't realise that thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using a mysqli connection but trying the deprecated mysql functions.

try [mysqli_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) instead